# Use angular universal without Webpack

Tags: angular, express, webpack, angular-universal

How can I use angular universal without bundling the API code with Webpack? Webpack overcomplicates back end code that depends on the original file system setup.

When I simply use `tsc` to compile the app, it doesn't work for imported files that don't use dependency injection. Is there an Angular CLI command that builds the app for the server without including the api code? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: I assume you are trying to set up server-side rendering with `@nguniversal/express-engine`. What backend technology are you using? ASP.NET Core, express.js, Symphony?

Comment: Why would webpack bundle your API code when using universal? With angular, webpack only bundles files needed to run the application, not the API. Unless you mixed everything in your project?

Comment: @David when following the guide on angular.io, it adds a server.ts file which allows you to add api code. It packs that into a Webpack bundle.

Comment: @Pieterjan I’m using express, works fine for the most part. But angular bundles the server code as well, which doesn’t allow the use of `fs.readdir` because there is no file system structure anymore.

Comment: Can't you just move your API to another project? Or just another file and compile it yourself? Otherwise this might help: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus

Comment: @David I can use another project. Do you suggest using a separate server for the server side rendering and the api?

Comment: Yes, you can use a separate nodejs server.

Comment: I know I can. But that’s a bit overkill to have two servers

Comment: Separating API and front end processes is usually a good practice.

Comment: @David serving pages is not really a front end process, right? The default server.ts file has a spot for API code

Comment: Otherwise rewrite your code to make your `fs.*` calls work. Hard to tell without any code though

Comment: I would, but the `fs.readdir` call is in a 3rd-party package for database migrations that loads migrations from a folder